# Error al mostrar dato de un Json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

¿Por qué me marca `undefined` al momento de visualizar los datos del `Json`?

Código `Javascript`:

```
function getNota()
{
    var id_temporada = $("#temporadaVal").val();
    var jornada = $("#jornadaVal").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/acciones/nota/getNota.php",
        data: "id_temporada=" + id_temporada + "&jornada=" + jornada, 
        async: true,
        success: function(data)
        {   
         var nota = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         alert(nota.id_nota);
         //$("#id_notaVal").val(nota.id_nota);
         //$("#nota").html(nota.nota);
        }
    });
}
```

Código php getNota.php

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Juego.php");
include_once("../../clases/class.Nota.php");

extract($_POST);
# id_temporada
# jornada

$fecha = Juego::getFecha($jornada);

$nota = Nota::getNota($id_temporada, $fecha);

$arrayNota = array();

if(is_array($nota))
{
 $arrayNota[] = array("id_nota" => $nota[0]["id_nota"], "nota" => strip_tags($nota[0]["nota"]));
}

echo json_encode($arrayNota);
?>
```

Comment: indica en que linea te marca el error y añade la estructura del json

Comment: No marca ningún error

Comment: podes hacerle un var dump al arrayNota asi verificas si esta seteado lo que estas intentado acceder por json

Comment: @JorgeAlonso, antes de esta línea: `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` use `console.log(data);` y [edit] la pregunta con los resultados.

Comment: Puede ser que tu PHP esté devolviendo un array e intentes acceder a una propiedad de un objeto, sin entrar en ningún elemento de ese array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi el problema, leyendo algunos de los comentarios que me pusieron, lo que devuelo es un array y no un objeto por lo que al momento de mostrar los datos tenia que poner la posición en la que se encuentran esos datos.

```
function getNota()
{
    var id_temporada = $("#temporadaVal").val();
    var jornada = $("#jornadaVal").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../includes/acciones/nota/getNota.php",
        data: "id_temporada=" + id_temporada + "&jornada=" + jornada, 
        async: true,
        success: function(data)
        {   
         var nota = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         alert(nota[0]["id_nota"]);
         //$("#id_notaVal").val(nota.id_nota);
         //$("#nota").html(nota.nota);
        }
    });
}
```